# PHP - PDO using the LIKE statement

Tags: php, pdo

Im using PDO, i have a query that needs to add the LIKE statement but the script fails as nothing is returned back. Everything was working fine until i had to add a search item to the query string which this search item would be used for the LIKE statement.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

        include "connect.php";

        $catId = 0;
        $start = '';
        $lastTS = '';
        $searchItem = '';

        if(isset($_REQUEST['Category'])){
            $catId = $_REQUEST['Category'];
        }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['Start'])){
            $start = $_REQUEST['Start'];
        }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['LastTS'])){
            $lastTS = $_REQUEST['LastTS'];
        }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['SearchItem'])){
            $searchItem = $_REQUEST['SearchItem'];
        }

        if($searchItem != ''){

            $searchItem = '%' . $searchItem . '%';

        }

        if($start == 'start'){
            if($catId > 0){
                $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.*, u.U_FirstName, u.U_LastName, c.C_Name FROM T_Thread t INNER JOIN U_User u ON t.T_U_ID = u.U_ID INNER JOIN C_Category c ON t.T_C_ID = c.C_ID WHERE t.T_C_ID = :catId AND t.T_Name LIKE :searchItem ORDER BY t.T_ID DESC LIMIT 10");
                $q->execute(array(':catId' => $catId, ':searchItem' => $searchItem));
            }else{
                $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.*, u.U_FirstName, u.U_LastName, c.C_Name FROM T_Thread t INNER JOIN U_User u ON t.T_U_ID = u.U_ID INNER JOIN C_Category c ON t.T_C_ID = c.C_ID WHERE t.T_Name LIKE :searchItem ORDER BY t.T_ID DESC LIMIT 10");
                $q->execute(':searchItem' => $searchItem);
            }
        }else{
            if($catId > 0){
                $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.*, u.U_FirstName, u.U_LastName, c.C_Name FROM T_Thread t INNER JOIN U_User u ON t.T_U_ID = u.U_ID INNER JOIN C_Category c ON t.T_C_ID = c.C_ID WHERE t.T_C_ID = :catId AND t.T_Created > :lastTS AND t.T_Name LIKE :searchItem ORDER BY t.T_ID DESC");
                $q->execute(array(':catId' => $catId, ':lastTS' => $lastTS, ':searchItem' => $searchItem));
            }else{
                $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.*, u.U_FirstName, u.U_LastName, c.C_Name FROM T_Thread t INNER JOIN U_User u ON t.T_U_ID = u.U_ID INNER JOIN C_Category c ON t.T_C_ID = c.C_ID WHERE t.T_Created > :lastTS AND t.T_Name LIKE :searchItem ORDER BY t.T_ID DESC");
                $q->execute(array(':lastTS' => $lastTS, ':searchItem' => $searchItem));
            }
        }

        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
            $threads[] = $r;
        }


        $arr = array('thread' => $threads);

        echo json_encode($arr);

        $conn = null;

    ?>
```

### UPDATE

If i use this bit of code, without the search item it works fine:

```
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.*, u.U_FirstName, u.U_LastName, c.C_Name FROM T_Thread t INNER JOIN U_User u ON t.T_U_ID = u.U_ID INNER JOIN C_Category c ON t.T_C_ID = c.C_ID ORDER BY t.T_ID DESC LIMIT 10");
        $q->execute();
```

But when i use this with search item, does not work:

```
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.*, u.U_FirstName, u.U_LastName, c.C_Name FROM T_Thread t INNER JOIN U_User u ON t.T_U_ID = u.U_ID INNER JOIN C_Category c ON t.T_C_ID = c.C_ID WHERE t.T_Name LIKE :searchItem ORDER BY t.T_ID DESC LIMIT 10");
        $q->execute(':searchItem' => $searchItem);
```

And if i hard code the value, everything works:

```
        $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.*, u.U_FirstName, u.U_LastName, c.C_Name FROM T_Thread t INNER JOIN U_User u ON t.T_U_ID = u.U_ID INNER JOIN C_Category c ON t.T_C_ID = c.C_ID WHERE t.T_Name LIKE '%uu%' ORDER BY t.T_ID DESC LIMIT 10");
        $q->execute();
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is in the `LIKE` statement..? What have you done to debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in the following line:

```
$q->execute(':searchItem' => $searchItem);
```

Try:

```
$q->execute(array(':searchItem' => $searchItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing:

```
...
$q->execute(array(':searchItem' => '%'.$searchItem.'%'));
```